# Signed time deltas to signed seconds in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time, timedelta

Consider the following series:

```
> df['time_delta']

0   -1 days +00:08:11
1     0 days 01:57:46
2     0 days 00:58:34
3     0 days 17:30:23
4   -1 days +21:44:34
5   -2 days +22:01:56
6     0 days 03:18:57
7   -1 days +21:44:48
8   -1 days +00:07:56
Name: time_delta, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Say I want to convert this timedelta to **total** **signed** seconds. That is:

- **Positive** deltas should convert to **positive** seconds
- **Negative** deltas should convert to **negative** seconds

For example:

- `0 days 00:01:05`  => `65` seconds
- `-1 days +23:58:30` => `-90` seconds

How can I get this conversion?

---

#### Failed attempt

When I try the usual:

```
temp_df['seconds'] = temp_df['time_delta'].dt.seconds
```

I end up with:

```
         time_delta  seconds
0 -1 days +00:08:11      491
1   0 days 01:57:46     7066
2   0 days 00:58:34     3514
3   0 days 17:30:23    63023
4 -1 days +21:44:34    78274
5 -2 days +22:01:56    79316
6   0 days 03:18:57    11937
7 -1 days +21:44:48    78288
8 -1 days +00:07:56      476
```

which correctly handled **positive** deltas, but **not** the negative ones. To see this, note that the negative deltas seem to ignore the **sign** of the day offset. That is, in the example above:

- `-1 days +21:44:48` should convert to `-8112` seconds, not `78288` seconds (wrong sign and value).

---

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's a [`Timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timedeltas.html) object, just divide it by `Timedelta(seconds=1)`:

```
>>> pd.Timedelta(days=-1) / pd.Timedelta(seconds=1)
-86400.0
```

Comment: You'd still need to get rid of the `-`ve sign though so won't you need to call `abs` on this anyway?

Comment: Great solution. This works right away without having to handle signs in a separate step.

Comment: @EdChum I see your point. To me this seems simpler (it doesn't require knowing `dt` and `total_seconds`). Eyes of the beholder, I guess. I'm usually a huge fan of your answers.

Comment: FYI, the reason ``.seconds`` gives that answer in the OP question is because its a sub-class of ``datetime.timedelta`` : https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects, its the ``seconds`` of the object, NOT the total_seconds.

Comment: Thanks, @Jeff - that was my understanding too when I answered this.

Answer (score 2):

just call [`abs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.abs.html) prior to `dt.total_seconds` to get the absolute values:

```
df['seconds'] = df['time_delta'].abs().dt.total_seconds()
```

Example:

```
In [63]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'date_time':pd.date_range(dt.datetime(2015,1,1,12,10,32), dt.datetime(2015,1,3,12,12,30,2))})
df['time_delta'] = df['date_time'] - dt.datetime(2015,1,2)
df

Out[63]:
            date_time        time_delta
0 2015-01-01 12:10:32 -1 days +12:10:32
1 2015-01-02 12:10:32   0 days 12:10:32
2 2015-01-03 12:10:32   1 days 12:10:32

In [64]:    
df['time_delta'].abs().dt.total_seconds()

Out[64]:
0     42568
1     43832
2    130232
Name: time_delta, dtype: float64
```

To add the signs back you can compare against `pd.Timedelta(0)`:

```
In [78]:
df['seconds'] = df['time_delta'].abs().dt.total_seconds()
df.loc[df['time_delta'] < pd.Timedelta(0), 'seconds'] = -df['seconds']
df

Out[78]:
            date_time        time_delta  seconds
0 2015-01-01 12:10:32 -1 days +12:10:32   -42568
1 2015-01-02 12:10:32   0 days 12:10:32    43832
2 2015-01-03 12:10:32   1 days 12:10:32   130232
```

However, I think @Ami Tamory's answer is superior

**EDIT**
After sleeping on this I realised that this is just `dt.total_seconds`:

```
In [137]:
df['time_delta'].dt.total_seconds()

Out[137]:
0    -42568
1     43832
2    130232
Name: time_delta, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks.  Good to know. I noticed that sign indexing didn't work right away in other cases (e.g. see [this other Q](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34793989/filtering-negative-timedeltas)), but it's good to know with `abs()`. For completeness, to get exactly what I am looking for with your answer, I think I can later change the sign of the result of using `abs` based on whether or not the original value is above or below than `pd.Timedelta(0)` as in [this other Q](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34793989/filtering-negative-timedeltas).

Comment: Yes originally I thought I was going to need to do something like that but then thought won't just `abs` work and it did so it's simpler

Comment: @EdChum I think it can be done in a shorter way (my answer below).